# Cloud Foundry: Run custom command before buildpack

Tags: cloud-foundry

Is there a way to run a one (or more) commands before the python.buildpack (or any buildpack) runs when doing a CF push? I have a Sphinx user guide I want to ship with my Django app. Since python.buildpack runs `collectstatic` to collect static files for the Django app, it fails to find the files because it has not been built.

My manifest.yml file looks like this but it fails to run as the commands in the python.buildpack run first.

```
---
applications:
- name: myapp
  command: make -C docs html && gunicorn -w 9 --pythonpath src/myapp myapp.wsgi --log-file -
  instances: 3
  memory: 2048M
  disk_quota: 1024M
  buildpacks:
    - https://github.com/cloudfoundry/python-buildpack.git
  stack: cflinuxfs3
  env:
    DJANGO_MODE: Production
```

Comment: With the advent of multi-buildpacks, you can create your own buildpack and have it run before the Python buildpack. You would basically need to add a `supply` script, https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/understand-buildpacks.html#supply-script and have it run whatever you need, in a general sense. What you're talking about could be tricky, if it needs Python you can't really run before the Python buildpack which installs Python. I suppose you could consider building your user guide locally & pushing it with the app, or building as part of CI and pushing that.

Comment: Thank you. I reverted to just building the guide locally and then doing cf push. It works fine that way.